# Screen rotation issue in my applicatin in android?

Tags: java, android, rotation, screen-orientation

My code to set screen orientation for my application is not working my phone hang ??

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    float width = display.getWidth();
    float height = display.getHeight();
    if (width>height)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    // then

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

**EDIT 1 : Solved**

```
   and also can i prevent the content to reload on screen rotation?
```

**EDIT 2 :**

> ```
>  CAn i prevent activity to reload when call is recieved specially problem is with list view it just flushed.
> ```

Please answer **Edit 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My criteria with answer someups to

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
float width = display.getWidth();
float height = display.getHeight();
if (width>height)
{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

add this inside your activity tag under application

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: or landscape... whichever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your criteria but the way to set screen orientation is:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: He is requested landscape, so the first part of your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one in your android menifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

for landscap

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

if you want  unspecified

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```